# How can I implement real-time sentiment analysis on live audio streams using Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, real-time, sentiment-analysis, audio-processing

I'm currently working on a project where I need to perform real-time sentiment analysis on live audio streams using Python. The goal is to analyze the sentiment expressed in the spoken words and provide insights in real-time. I've done some research and found resources on text-based sentiment analysis, but I'm unsure about how to adapt these techniques to audio streams.

**Context and Efforts:**

Research: I've researched various libraries and tools for sentiment analysis, such as Natural Language Processing (NLP) libraries like NLTK and spaCy. However, most resources I found focus on text data rather than audio.

Audio Processing: I'm familiar with libraries like pyaudio and soundfile in Python for audio recording and processing. I've successfully captured live audio streams using these libraries.

Text-to-Speech Conversion: I've experimented with converting the spoken words from the audio streams into text using libraries like SpeechRecognition to prepare the data for sentiment analysis.

**Challenges:**

Sentiment Analysis: My main challenge is adapting the sentiment analysis techniques to audio data. I'm not sure if traditional text-based sentiment analysis models can be directly applied to audio, or if there are specific approaches for this scenario.

Real-Time Processing: I'm also concerned about the real-time aspect of the analysis. How can I ensure that the sentiment analysis is performed quickly enough to provide insights in real-time without introducing significant delays?

**Question:**

I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to implement real-time sentiment analysis on live audio streams using Python. Are there any specialized libraries or techniques for audio-based sentiment analysis that I should be aware of? How can I effectively process the audio data and perform sentiment analysis in real-time? Any insights, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found here by following these steps:

- Adding middleware to make text from video
- Running the sentiment analysis for each **complete sentence** (Using Whisper as @doneforaiur suggested)

**So, the latency here depends on the length of the words of the sentence. It's a trade-off for getting the analysis for the full context. Making chunks doesn't reflect the whole sentence thus the complete context.**

There is a possible way to extend this by adding multiple sentence feeds to the analysis system to get deeper context. I'm thinking about it. Sometimes, we describe a scenario with multiple sentences.

Thanks, **@doneforaiur** for setting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Using a smaller model of [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) (for real-time performance) and feeding the speech-to-text output through a sentiment analysis pipeline with HuggingFace like so:

```
import whisper
from transformers import pipeline

model = whisper.load_model("small")
stt_result = model.transcribe("audio.mp3")

sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
data = [stt_result]
sentiment_pipeline(data)
```

would achieve your desired results as such:

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.995}]
```

Altough you should keep in mind that in this example, Whisper doesn't accept a stream of data but a file. You should orchestrate the stream like this:

1. Save incoming audio data.
2. Transcribe last 5 seconds (the more the better) of your saved audio file.
3. If there's an overlap, select most recent segment's transcription.
4. Repeat steps 1-3.

As a last note; this [GitHub project](https://github.com/davabase/whisper_real_time) that transcribes (and deals with the orchestration) an audio stream. Adding the mentioned sentiment analysis pipeline would be much easier in your case.

Comment: So a middleware to make chunks of audio files is an option in your given solution. If I take it in 5sec of data, the latency will be 5sec compared to live streaming.

Comment: Exactly. You could shorten the window to 1 second, for instance, but you would still need to merge the previous audio files together to make sure that spoken words remain continuous across segments. However, you're correct; the delay will correspond to the duration of your window, and the sentimental score of the audio may alter beyond that point but will catch up eventually.

Comment: To make sure that spoken words remain continuous across segments, need to merge previous chunks, I think I would have to set a pointer to mark the analysis completion. Let me explain,

Here is a sentence

"Discover the only tool you need for civil design projects - from roads to bridges to rail, from planning through delivery. Get the e-book."

We will not know how fast the speaker will go or vice versa. But the whole sentence has a context. If I make a chunk of this audio and get the complete analysis, the whole sentence needs to feed into the model.

Comment: Here if the speaker takes 20sec to complete this sentence, and If I take 5sec chunks, I have to set the pointer before 4 chunks to get the full analysis.

Comment: The question is, how we will determine the pointer placement? Otherwise it may be end up with a wrong analysis due to incomplete context. Isn't it?

What's your thought on it?

Comment: You might want to do sentiment analysis for every sentence, if I got you right. You can't be sure that the words are correct unless Whisper processed one specific chunk twice. You might even split a word into two words that is not originally offensive but a negative word in the first chunk, for example "Penistone" is a village in England and may yield contradictory results. I think you can't overcome this by only processing 1 chunk at a time, you'd have to concatane with previous chunks as explained earlier. Also; I think computing sentiment analysis 4 times for your example is acceptable.

Comment: You'd have to display the most recent sentiment analysis score and discard earlier results.